# ResponseCollectionSerializable in swift 3

Tags: json, swift, get, alamofire

I am new to Swift, and am not able to figure out how to deserialize a JSON array to an array of Swift objects. I'm able to deserialize a single JSON user to a Swift channel object fine, but just not sure how to do it with a JSON array of channels.

My ResponseCollectionSerializable.swift

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

public protocol ResponseObjectSerializable {
    init?(response: HTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject)
}

extension Request {
    public func responseObject<T: ResponseObjectSerializable>(completionHandler: Response<T, NSError> -> Void) -> Self {
        let responseSerializer = DataResponseSerializer<T, NSError> { request, response, data, error in
            guard error == nil else { return .Failure(error!) }

            let JSONResponseSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .AllowFragments)
            let result = JSONResponseSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, data, error)

            switch result {
            case .Success(let value):
                if let
                    response = response,
                    let responseObject = T(response: response, representation: value)
                {
                    return .Success(responseObject)
                } else {
                    let failureReason = "JSON could not be serialized into response object: \(value)"
                    let error = Error.errorWithCode(.JSONSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
                    return .Failure(error)
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                return .Failure(error)
            }
        }

        return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}

public protocol ResponseCollectionSerializable {
    static func collection(response: HTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) -> [Self]
}

extension Alamofire.Request {
    public func responseCollection<T: ResponseCollectionSerializable>(completionHandler: Response<[T], NSError> -> Void) -> Self {
        let responseSerializer = DataResponseSerializer<[T], NSError> { request, response, data, error in
            guard error == nil else { return .Failure(error!) }

            let JSONSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .AllowFragments)
            let result = JSONSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, data, error)

            switch result {
            case .Success(let value):
                if let response = response {
                    return .Success(T.collection(response: response, representation: value))
                } else {
                    let failureReason = "Response collection could not be serialized due to nil response"
                    let error = Error.errorWithCode(.JSONSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
                    return .Failure(error)
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                return .Failure(error)
            }
        }

        return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

I have a problem : 
Use of undeclared type 'Response'
Generic type 'DataResponseSerializer' specialized with too many type parameters (got 2 but expected 1)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rlp5D.png)

My model :

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper
import SwiftyJSON

class AllCnannelModel : ResponseObjectSerializable, ResponseCollectionSerializable{

    var id : Int
    var  name: String
    var  url : String
    var  picture : String
    var  category_id: Int

    public required init?(response: HTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) {
        self.id = representation["id"] as! Int
        self.name = representation["name"] as! String
        self.url = representation["url"] as! String
        self.picture = representation["picture"] as! String
        self.category_id = representation["category_id"] as! Int
    }

    class func collection(response: HTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) -> [AllCnannelModel] {
        let postArray = representation as! [AnyObject]

        return postArray.map({ AllCnannelModel(response:response, representation: $0)! })
    }

}
```

problem :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6w1y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer begins with [the approach that the SwiftyJSON GitHub readme recommends](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#work-with-alamofire) for building a SwiftyJSON object from an Alamofire response. The question did not include the equivalent of the `Alamofire.request()` call shown below. This removes the need for some of the methods in the question.

```
Alamofire.request("(put the URL here)", method: .get).validate().responseJSON { response in

    switch response.result {
    case .success(let value):

        let json = JSON(value)
        print("JSON: \(json)")

        if let array = json.array {
            var channelArray: [AllCnannelModel] = []
            for item in array {
                guard let dictionary = item.dictionaryObject else {
                    continue
                }
                if let channel = AllCnannelModel(representation: dictionary) {
                    channelArray.append(channel)
                }
            }
            // Do something with channelArray
        }

    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

The `AllCnannelModel` initializer has been modified to accept a dictionary, `[String: Any]`.

```
class AllCnannelModel {

    var id : Int
    var  name: String
    var  url : String
    var  picture : String
    var  category_id: Int

    public required init?(representation: [String: Any]) {
        self.id = representation["id"] as! Int
        self.name = representation["name"] as! String
        self.url = representation["url"] as! String
        self.picture = representation["picture"] as! String
        self.category_id = representation["category_id"] as! Int
    }
}
```